# Altair missing value in graph

Tags: python, missing-data, altair

I would like to vizualize a dataframe using altair.
It is a line and a barchart in one graph, drawn for each group (ID) in my dataframe.
My dataframe has missing values. According to https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/impute.html
missing entries are skipped and a line is drawn across the missing data point.
This is actually what I want, but with my data this does not seem to work.
I get a break in my line graph where the value is missing.
I prepared a simple example to explain my problem:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05', '2020-04-06','2020-04-03', '2020-04-04','2020-04-05','2020-04-06'],
                    'ID': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],'bar': [np.nan,8,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan, 8,np.nan,np.nan],
                    'line': [8,np.nan,10,8, 4, 5,6,7] })

df:
         date ID  bar  line
0  2020-04-03  a  NaN   8.0
1  2020-04-04  a  8.0   NaN
2  2020-04-05  a  NaN  10.0
3  2020-04-06  a  NaN   8.0
4  2020-04-03  b  NaN   4.0
5  2020-04-04  b  8.0   5.0
6  2020-04-05  b  NaN   6.0
7  2020-04-06  b  NaN   7.0

# create graph
bars = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(color="grey", size=5).encode(
         alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='bar:Q')

lines = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True,size=2,).encode(
            alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='line:Q')

alt.layer(bars + lines,width=350,height=150).facet(facet=alt.Facet('ID:N'),
    ).resolve_axis(y='independent',x='independent')
```

it gives this image
[image]

Has anyone an idea why the line has a break (a) and how to draw the line through the missing data point?
I know I could use "impute" to calculate the mean and replace the missing value.
But this implies a data point for the date which is actually not true.

Thanks for any hints, ideas or help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have the value recorded as NaN in the dataframe, so there is a valid date entry for this observation, and an NaN for the y-xis which can't be plotted.

This is what you have currently:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05', '2020-04-06','2020-04-03', '2020-04-04','2020-04-05','2020-04-06'],
                    'ID': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                    'line': [8,np.nan,10,8, 4, 5,6,7] })

alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True,size=2,).encode(
            alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='line:Q')
```

[image]

If you drop the NaNs, you will get the behavior that you want

```
alt.Chart(df.dropna()).mark_line(point=True,size=2).encode(
            alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='line:Q')
```

[image]

For your example above if you want the barplot to retain all values and not drop the rows with NaN in the line column, while still using both layer and facet, you need to reference the same dataframe in both charts an use Altair's `transform_filter` instead of pandas `dropna`:

```
(alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True,size=2)
 .transform_filter('isValid(datum.line)')
 .encode(alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='line:Q'))
```

Comment: Hi joelostblom, thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately I get an error when including dropna.
`ValueError: Facet charts require data to be specified at the top level`
not sure what that means?

Comment: @Aham With your example above, drop the NaNs from the dataframe when you create it, so that all the charts are passed the same data. To make sure that there is still data to plot, only drop the rows that have NaN values in the `line` column with `.dropna(subset=['line'])`

Comment: Hi joelostblom, the "dropna" I used only on the "line" part of the graph, not bars. Just like below,
was that what you meant?
`lines = alt.Chart(df.dropna()).mark_line(point=True,size=2,).encode(
            alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='line:Q')`
It gives the error: `ValueError: Facet charts require data to be specified at the top level`
Using  `...alt.Chart(df.dropna(subset=['line'])).mark_line....` gives the same error.
Is this because the dataframe used for the lines and the bars is not the same anymore (different length???).

Comment: Hey @Aham I mean to use it when you create the df, I added an example at the end of my answer that works for me.

Comment: Hi joelostblom, I tried your example, thank you. The problem is, it seems that row 1 (2020-04-04) is deleted completely. In consequence the bar at that date is also missing. Is there any way to keep the value in the bar-column? Maybe I had to work with two different dataframes (one for bars and one for lines)? But I did not manage to use two dataframes of different length and draw them both in a single layered graph using altair.

Comment: @Aham Hmm, I believe it is possible to layer or facet individually, but you can only do them together if tyou have the same df referenced in both charts, I changed the end of my answer above to include the altair method of filtering in stead of pandas dropna so that you can use `df` for both charts. This works for layering and facetting together.

Comment: Hi joelostblom, great, that works. thank you very much!