# Connecting lines over NaNs without dropping entire rows from the dataframe

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have my code set up as follows

```
    df = t_sepsis_col_adder(filename)
    if df['SepsisLabel'].sum() > 0:
        cols = list(df.columns)
        cols_to_remove = ['Age', 'Gender', 'Unit1', 'Unit2', 'T_Sepsis', 'SepsisLabel', 'HospAdmTime']
        for col in cols:
            if df[col].isnull().all():
                cols_to_remove.append(col)
        for col in cols_to_remove:
            cols.remove(col)
        col_l, col_r = cols[:len(cols) // 2], cols[len(cols) // 2:]
        chart_l = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
            alt.X(alt.repeat("column"), type='quantitative', 
                  sort="descending"),
            alt.Y(alt.repeat("row"), type='quantitative', 
                  scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
            order="T_Sepsis"
        ).properties(
            width=600,
            height=100
        ).repeat(
            row=col_l,
            column=['T_Sepsis']
        )
        chart_l.save("chart_l.png")
        
        chart_r = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
            alt.X(alt.repeat("column"), type='quantitative', 
                  sort="descending"),
            alt.Y(alt.repeat("row"), type='quantitative', 
                  scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
            order="T_Sepsis"
        ).properties(
            width=600,
            height=100
        ).repeat(
            row=col_r,
            column=['T_Sepsis']
        )
        chart_concat = alt.hconcat(chart_l, chart_r)
```

I essentially have a lot of features to plot so I decided to split the different plots into two columns. The issue is that the line plots don't actually connect to the points most of the time. I will attach a screenshot below. Any ideas on how to go about fixing this issue? By the way, the issue still persists if I stick to a single column of plots so I don't think repeat is causing the issue here. It's also worth noting that my data has a lot of NaN values (which I am choosing not to pre-process and take care of since I need to plot the raw data). Thanks!

[Part of the main chart](https://gyazo.com/6f587c31243fc54e77717fcc24178cea)

Edit: In addition to the above code, here is the function `t_sepsis_col_adder`.

```
def t_sepsis_col_adder(filename: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Adds a column that gives the time till t_sepsis at each time step.

    Args:
        filename: name of the file being processed

    Returns:
        Returns a dataframe with the new column
    """
    df = df_instantiator_unaugmented(filename)
    number_of_sepsis_hours = df['SepsisLabel'].sum()
    if number_of_sepsis_hours > 0:
        if number_of_sepsis_hours >= 7:
            first_occurrence = df['SepsisLabel'].idxmax()
            t_sepsis = first_occurrence + 6
        else:
            t_sepsis = len(df.index) - 1
        
        temp_list = []
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            temp_list.append(t_sepsis - i)
        df['T_Sepsis'] = temp_list
    else:
        t_end_recording = len(df.index)
        temp_list = []
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            temp_list.append(t_end_recording - i - 1)
        df['T_EndRecording'] = temp_list
    return df
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Altair missing value in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348548/altair-missing-value-in-graph)

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm without a reproducible example, but this is likely due to there being NaNs in the data. These are not connected by Altair/VegaLite by default, whereas values that are missing would be connected. You can fix this by using `dropna(subset=['column_name'])` in pandas or `.transform_filter('isValid(datum.column_name)')` in Altair. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356140/2166823) for examples.

What I reference above also work for faceting, here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05', '2020-04-06',
                            '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04','2020-04-05','2020-04-06'],
                    'ID': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                    'line': [8,np.nan,10,8, 4, 5,6,7] })
df
```

```sh
## out
    date        ID  line
0   2020-04-03  a   8.0
1   2020-04-04  a   NaN
2   2020-04-05  a   10.0
3   2020-04-06  a   8.0
4   2020-04-03  b   4.0
5   2020-04-04  b   5.0
6   2020-04-05  b   6.0
7   2020-04-06  b   7.0
```

`transform_filter` only exclude points from individual facets, not entire rows.

```
(alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
            alt.X('monthdate(date):O'), y='line:Q')
 .transform_filter('isValid(datum.line)')
 .facet('ID'))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @joelostblom. Thank you very much for the response. Unfortunately, it seems like your suggestions are dropping the rows with NaN values (which I can't afford to do since I lose the non-NaN valued data in the other columns from that particular row). I am going to attach a .psv file of the record I am working with, it is publicly available data so it shouldn't be an issue. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bv0f7nyxsdq37bo/p009573.psv?dl=0 Here is a download to it. Please note that I want to keep the data I already have but ignore the NaN values and connect the data present on the plots.

Comment: Additionally, I've edited my original question so it has the required function to add that extra column (T_Sepsis which is our x-axis variable) to the dataframe. The `df_instantiator_unaugmented` function in the newly added code simply calls `pd.read_csv` with the appropriate arguments (directory of the psv file and separator being |)

Comment: @adil.a Did you try with `transform_filter` as I suggested in my answer? It sounds like it would do exactly what you want and I included and example of how it looks with facets.

Comment: And thanks for posting your data @adil.a, unfortunately I can't run it because `df_instantiator_unaugmented` is not defined anywhere. If the sample above doesn't work, please include a snippet of your data as text either here or uploaded elsewhere so it can be read directly with pandas.

Comment: @adil.a Were you able to solve your issue with this answer?