# Python Altair, `mark_line()`, _ignore_ NaN instead of _skipping_ them or treating them as 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, altair, vega-lite

As far as I can see, for example [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks.html), the only two ways Altair handles NaNs is either `"filter"` or `None`. In the context of `mark_line()`, `"filter"` means that the NaN will be *skipped*, which means that there will be a break in the line, and `None` means that NaN would be treated as zero, which would be insane in my application LOL. Is there a way to make Altair *ignore*, **not** *skip*, NaNs, when drawing a line? So that the line isn't broken in the middle?

I know I can always prune out the NaNs from the Pandas `Dataframe` by hand before plotting the line, but that would be incredibly inconvenient when there are several columns that I want to plot at the same time, each having NaNs in different places. It would be nearly impossible, as far as I know, to plot that **and** have nice things like a hover tool that shows all column values at the same time and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `.transform_filter('isValid(datum.line)')` as these two answers:

- [Altair missing value in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348548/altair-missing-value-in-graph)
- [Connecting lines over NaNs without dropping entire rows from the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66652941/connecting-lines-over-nans-without-dropping-entire-rows-from-the-dataframe)

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05', '2020-04-06','2020-04-03', '2020-04-04','2020-04-05','2020-04-06'],
    'ID': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
    'line': [8,np.nan,10,8, 4, 5,6,7]
}).pipe(
    alt.Chart
).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    alt.X('monthdate(date):O'),
    y='line:Q'
).transform_filter(
    'isValid(datum.line)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah right. Didn't come across your second link. Title reads like exactly what I want LOL. Thank you.